# To catch the start of a sequence from a file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file which goes like this :

```
      125
      126
      127    {
      566
      567
      568
      569       # blah blah
      570    {  #blah blah
      700
      701    {
```

The numbers are left aligned and the pattern is always the same in the sense increasing and a curly braces at the end .I need to catch just the starting number .The braces are always found and  limited to the sequence end .The start of the file is as shown starting with '125'.

In short I need :

```
      125
      566
      700
```

What I have come up with :

```
      grep -A1 '{' | grep -v '{' | grep -oE '(^[0-9]+?)'
```

but this omits '125' but I overcame by appending a newline at the head and inserting a `{` .

I hope to reduce this into a single regex.

Suggestions and better algorithms are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {p=1} p==1 {print $1;p=0} $0~/{/ {p=1}'

Output:
125
566
700
```

Given the file format above, you could use awk and a variable/flag to keep track on when you find an opening `{`

Comment: `$0~/.*\{.*/` is excessively verbose. An equivalent expression is: `/{/`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '1p;/{/{
N
s/.*\n\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p
}' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to tweak the regex, but:

```
awk '!k; { k = !/^ *[0-9]* *{/ }'
```

This will print the first line and any line following a line that matches the regex `^ *[0-9]* *{`
You could probably simplify things and do:

```
awk '!k;{k=$2!="{"}'
```

Which will print the first line and any line following a line in which the second field is a single open brace.

Comment: Changing your regexp to what you suggested above would make this a really nice solution

Comment: @Karl, but reducing the regex to match just '{' greatly increases the likelihood of false hits.

Comment: true, the comment could in principle also contain a '{'. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk and a flag to capture the existence of a curly brace and print the next line. Set the flag in the beginning and you'll get the first line.

Untested, but something like:

```
BEGIN {hasCurly = 1}
{ 
    if(hasCurly) 
        print $1;

    hasCurly = match($2,"^\{");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bash solution:

```
start=1
while read n rest; do
    if (( start )); then
        printf '%d\n' $n
        start=0
    elif [[ $rest = \{* ]]; then
        start=1
    fi
done < input
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will win in code golf competition =) :

```
sed -n '1p;/{/{n;p}' file
```

To remove everything after the number use:

```
sed -n '1{s/\s*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/;p};/{/{n;s/\s*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/;p}' file
```

Comment: If you use the same regex, the awk solution beats sed: `awk '!k;{k=!/{/}'`

Comment: @KarlNordström I added the remove command to `sed`. So now it is pretty long.